# How can I have multiple forloops on my Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am a Django / Python newbie & trying to create multiple `forloop` on my template.
The result that I want is:

```
<ul>
  <li data-target="food-fruit1-0">Banana</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit1-1">Apple</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit1-2">Orange</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit1-3">Mango</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li data-target="food-fruit2-0">Banana</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit2-1">Apple</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit2-2">Orange</li>
  <li data-target="food-fruit2-3">Mango</li>
</ul>
```

How do I achieve it with Django Template `forloop`? I have tried

```
{% for fruit in fruit_list %}
    <ul class='h-clearlist'>
      {% for item in object.fruits %}
        <li class='fruit__list' data-target="food-fruit{{ forloop.counter1 }}-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
          <h3 class='fruit__title'>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <p class='fruit__description'>{{item.description}}</p>
          <span class="fruit__cost"> <strong data-currency>{{item.price}}</strong></span>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

But of course it's incorrect:( I tried using `{% with outer=1 inner=0 %}` but also not working. Can someone please help me out?
```

Comment: Hi! How can the code understand there should be two </ul> 's ? Is this static or can the code learn it from some variable?

Comment: Sorry @engin_ipek! I updated  the code. It's multiple for loops

Comment: check @chris's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a nested loop? For instance

```
{% for x in some_list %}
<ul>
{% for item in object.fruits %}
    <li data-target="food-fruit{{ forloop.parentloop.counter}}-{{ forloop.counter }}">
         {{ item.name }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)